# How close are we to building an actual nanobot?

Tags: reference-request, nanotechnology

I want to know how far current [nanotechnology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology) is from creating an actual real-world [nanorobot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanorobotics)? Also, does such a thing actually exist, or is it just a nice name for an umbrella term to show off to the general public different fields of science and engineering which might not be actually linked?

P.S. I understand that the term nanorobot may be taken into consideration because it may mean different things to different people, that's why when I use it I mean something bigger than a molecule but smaller than a biological cell which could replicate and do some "stuff" like the things described in Eric Drexler's book [Engines of Creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engines_of_Creation) or in foresight's institute [nanotechnology roadmap](http://www.foresight.org/roadmaps/Nanotech_Roadmap_2007_main.pdf). I guess they will be somewhat the size of [biological organelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organelle) and just like them be composed of various molecular complexes some capable of self assembly. I want to know what is the current state of research into the creation of such structures and how far are we from building them.

P. S. 2. And, please, guys can you not use only Wikipedia for your answers. I want to know what **serious** research is being done and where it's published in, not just a general introduction to the field. I'll be very thankful if you could provide some sound material published in peer reviewed journals or at least a list of keywords I could use for searching for articles related to the creation of real nanorobots or a list of journals where such research can be found. If you could do at least that you will have my gratitude.

Comment: You described the "nanostuff" quite accurately. "Real nanotechnology" is... biology :D

Comment: I just want to have the answer to a question about the current state of nanotechnology to its "ultimate" (if I could even use this word) goal of building something we can call a nanorobots.  think this section of SE communities is the best place to ask since there isn't one on nanotechnology and I couldn't find the question asked so clear anywhere on this site. Do you think here is the right place and this is the best way to ask it?

Comment: I would like to see your questions on a forum with a lot of discussion, but Stack Exchanges site *aren't* forums. Closest you can get may be [Worldbuilding. SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), where are various speculative and open ended questions.

Comment: I'm starting to see the limitations of this community, however, it's still the best community I had encountered so far on the Internet in terms of people who actually do **serious** science and aren't "bible mumblers"or "new age priest" trying to bring on some very twisted form of pseudoscience they use to further their ideology. I think I have something interesting to ask and offer however I have no job in science and can't get publish from the place I'm currently in, so my best option is asking questions here @Mithoron. What else do I have?

Comment: Actually your question isn't exactly clear. Various people talking about "nanobots" usually don't know what they are talking about. "Real nanobots" are [for example ribosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_machine#Biological)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66778/discussion-between-yordan-yordanov-and-mithoron).

Comment: Yes, nanotechnology does exist. And yes, this is an umbrella term. Before it came along, same researchers did the same stuff under different names. As for nanorobots: still pretty far.

Comment: Come on guys, why are you doing this? What's wrong with that question? There is nothing unchemical or broad here! I just want to know what is the current state of research on nanotechnology we are in? How is that not  right for Chemistry SE???

Comment: @YordanYordanov it is a debate/discussion type question with no objectively correct answer. First, nanorobot may mean many things, if you want, nanorobots already exist, second, it asks about the future and how it will unfold.

Comment: Yordan I came across your questions here and in biology SE. You are really aiming at some life or life mimicking stuff. Therefore, although I encourage you to keep curiosity and fantasy alive, you cannot be surprised if you find this site limited. It might be, but not because one cannot answer your questions which are always interesting but broad and, as it was clear to me in your (Ill posed) Q about single molecule and equilibrium or in the Q about single molecule life, at the border life/no life. Faced to a question like the current one I can only say, like others, "umbrella - term" .

Comment: @Alchimista I think you really would like to see this question of mine-https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91075/if-i-start-a-blog-to-spread-my-ideas-in-academia-could-it-be-successful . It says much more about my true intentions, than what I have written so far in either the chemistry or the biology SE sections.